# Are there adverse effects of passing around objects rather than assigning them as members of a class

Tags: oop

I have a habit of creating classes that tend to pass objects around to perform operations on them rather than assigning them to a member variable and having operations refer to the member variable. It feels much more procedural to me than OO.

Is this a terrible practice? If so, what are the adverse effects (performance, memory consumption, more error-prone)? Is it simply easier and more closely aligned to OO principles like encapsulation to favour member variables?

A contrived example of what I mean is below. I tend to do the following;

```
public class MyObj()
{

  public MyObj() {}

  public void DoVariousThings(OtherObj oo)
  {
    if (Validate(oo))
    {
       Save(oo);
    }
  }

  private bool Validate(OtherObj oo)
  {
    // Do stuff related to validation
  }

  private bool Save(OtherObj oo)
  {
     // Do stuff related to saving
  }

}
```

whereas I suspect I should be doing the following;

```
public class MyObj()
{

  private OtherObj _oo;

  public MyObj(OtherObj oo) 
  {
    _oo = oo;
  }

  public void DoVariousThings()
  {
    if (Validate())
    {
       Save();
    }
  }

  private bool Validate()
  {
    // Do stuff related to validation with _oo
  }

  private bool Save()
  {
     // Do stuff related to saving with _oo
  }
}
```

Comment: It depends on if the object in question logically should be a member of the class. Don't feel like you have to make classes and put members in them just for the sake of it. OO is not a silver bullet. However, if you have something that is conceptually an object, and it 'has-a'nother object, then by all means make it a member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you already answered your question yourself, you seem to be aware of the fact that the 2nd approach is more favorable in general and should be used (unless there are serious reasons for the first approach).

Advantages that come to my mind immediately:

- Simplified readability and maintainability, both for you and for others
- Only one entry point, therefore only needing to checking for != null etc.
- In case you want to put that class under test, it's way easier, i.e., getting something like this (extracting interface IOtherObj from OtherObj and working with that):

  ```
  public MyObj (IOtherObj oo)  
  {
      if (oo == null) throw...
      _oo = oo;
  }
  ```

Comment: Excessive null checking is something I do too often. Good point. I realise that the second option is certainly more favoured as an OO approach. The main instances where this occurs is in a Service class that has a publicly exposed interface. It's not always feasible to construct the service with a given service with a particular object, but sometimes my public methods will make use of private methods. In this instance, I tend to favour my first approach.

Comment: @Mr Moose, from what you tell odds are high that by using that approach, actually more sever problems with regard to the application design are covered. For instance, if you cannot construct that service at a particular point but nevertheless require some parameters afterwards, you might consider re-constructing your entire object afterwards. Therefore, a clean state of the object is ensured any time.

Answer (score 2):

If you write your programs in an object oriented language, people will expect object oriented code. As such, in your first example, they would probably **expect** that the reason for making `oo` a parameter is that you will use different objects for it all the time. In your second example, they would **know** that you always use the same instance (as initialized in the constructor).

Now, if you use the same object all the time, but still write your code like in your first example, you will have them thoroughly confused. When an interface is well designed, it should be obvious how to use it. This is not the case in your first example.

Comment: Do you mean "This is not the case in your first example"?

Comment: Good points Space_C0wb0y. Thanks. If the class in my example, was a service class where the class itself exists mainly to expose a particular interface to users and the actual work was performed by calloboraters of the class, would you think that the second example was acceptable?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by collaborators. You'd have to describe that in more detail, perhaps as an edit to your question, or even as a new question.

Comment: By callaborators, I mean other classes that the Service class depends on/works with to get the job done. In this instance, the service class does little else other than delegate the work to the callaborators, often through the use of the private methods to reduce the complexity of a given method by breaking it up, or alternatively using a private method to combine common code.

Comment: It's impossible to really say without seeing your design, but it sounds a little bit to me like you have contrived classes 'out of thin air' where there aren't really objects involved. It is, to an extent, a matter of opinion/taste, but my advice is don't let excess code get in the way writing a program that actually accomplishes a task. Too many interfaces/helper classes/collaborating classes may seem easier to write now, but can end up bloated and impossible for anyone else to comprehend/maintain. Try to make your code as small as (sensibly) possible.

Answer (score 0):

Talking of the adverse effects of your way, there are none, but only if you are keeping the programs and the code to yourself,, what are you doing is NOT a standard thing, say, if after some time, you start to work making libraries and code that may be used by others also, then it is a big problem. The may pass any foo object and hope that it would work.

you have to validate the object before passing it and if the validation fails do things accordingly, but if u use the standard OOP way, there is no need for validation or taking up the cases where an inappropriate type object is pass,

In a nutshell, your way is bad for :
1. code re-usability.
2. you have to handle more exceptions.
3. okay, if u r keeping things to urself, otherwise, not a good practice.

hope, it cleared some doubt.